# Upgrading libspatialite for Spatialite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, spatialite, geos

Hi I looked at this http://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/ about using the spatialite for android. I tried it and works fine.

Is it possible to upgrade the examples to use libspatialite-4.0.0 instead of libspatialite-amalgamation-3.0.1? If possible, can someone point a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spatialite-Android is maintained by [a third party](http://www.agc.army.mil/); you cannot expect them to upgrade, test, and release a new version a mere four days after the new libspatialite was released.

The easiest way to upgrade is to wait for them to do this.

It appears that nobody has done this yet, so if you are impatient, you have to do this yourself.

Comment: they have upgraded this, so I can try it now